# Which Control To Use For PHP Parsing Editor

Tags: php, parsing, editor

I want to develop an application with c#.net(winforms) to be a parser and editor for php.
I have many experiences in .net, but I am confused.
In fact I need to write an editor in which I can implement syntax coloring,
line numbers, gutters, expandable/collapsable regions, ...

I can write it with RichTextBox, but it has many difficulties.
Is there an easier way to do it, or is there a component to do this (free and source available of course), or ...
I want to know what various ways of doing this are.

Thanks for your replies

Answer (score 0):

I guess that [ScintillaNET](http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/) will do the trick. (Tho I've never used it my self)